# How to use db_select and apply a condition for another table's data?

Tags: 7, database

I know this is probably the dumbest question ever but I'm just not getting warm with SQL.

I am writing this function which loads all users that have a role assigned:

```
function mymodule_get_users_by_role($rolename) {
  $role = user_role_load_by_name($rolename);
  $uids = db_select('users_roles', 'ur')
      ->fields('ur', array('uid'))
      ->condition('ur.rid', $role->rid, '=')
      // ->leftJoin('users', 'us', '(us.uid = ur.uid AND us.status = 1)')
      ->execute()
      ->fetchCol();
  return user_load_multiple($uids);
}
```

But I only want those users which's `status = 1`. I could do it afterwards but I really hope there is a way within the QuerySelect to add this filter beforehands. The commented line just produces a white screen of death so I'ma go with a nope. I dont even know if leftJoin is the right thing to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you, basically, asking how to make a [join](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should be self-explanatory.

```
$query=db_select('table1','t1');
$query->join('table2','t2','t1.nid = t2.nid');

$query->condition('t1.uid','1')
      ->condition('t2.uid','3')
      ->fields('t1',array('uid','nid'))
      ->fields('t2',array('date'));
```

Comment: `$query = db_select('users_roles', 't1')
    ->join('users','t2', 't1.uid = t2.uid')
    ;
  $query->condition('t2.status', '1');` creates also a wod